# Кеш в Библиотеки Пикассо

Tags: android, android-studio, picasso

всем привет. В приложении под андроид использую для загрузки изоброжений с инета Библиотеку Пикассо. В приложения экономия трафика очень важна. Можно ли как то увелечить обьем кешируемов изоброжений?

Comment: https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1154

Comment: @Sviat Volkov это нужно вписать в начале каждого запросо или только при открытие стартового активити

Comment: один раз. пикассо работает как синглтон

Comment: @Sviat Volkov Большое спасибо